# VM error: revert. The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, remix

I have been trying for while for accessing functions of one contract in another one as shown below. I actually want to call the functions `changeName()` and `receiveName()` defined in the `foreignContract{}` from `myContract{}`. The transaction is getting mined but the execution is getting failed.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract myContract {
    foreignContract created;

    function myContract() {
        created = foreignContract(msg.sender);
    }

    function changeNameMycontract(string name) returns(bool, address) {
        return (created.changeName(name), msg.sender);    
    }

    function ReturnName()returns(string) {
        return created.receiveName();
    }
}

contract foreignContract {
    string name;

    function changeName(string Name) returns(bool) {
        name = Name;
        return true;
    }

    function receiveName() returns(string) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The error that I get is

> Transact to myContract.changeNameMycontract errored:VM error.reverted
>   revert the transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note:
>   the constructor should be payable if you send value.

I'm new to this solidity and blockchain concepts - any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Change your function to: function changeNameMycontract(string name) payable returns(bool,address)

Comment: @Soggiorno   Still the same error is there

Comment: How are you calling the function? If you call it by sending a transaction the function should have the payable modifier. I would recommend calling it using an external call (http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html)

Comment: i have put the payable modifier in both changeNameMyContract() and ReturnName(). If you could please explain exactly what the use of payable modifier?

Comment: If you send ETH  to a contract that has no function with a payable modifier the transaction will be reverted. You don't need to send ETH to it though, as you can just use the call syntax (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=getBlock#methods-mymethod-call)

Comment: so you mean i have to create a new contract and return its address and use it then? that is what meant by external call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pragma solidity ^ 0.4.24;


import "./foreignContract.sol";

contract myContract {

 foreignContract created;
 constructor() public payable {
  created = new foreignContract();
 }

 function changeNameMycontract(string name) public returns(bool) {
  return created.changeName(name);

 }

 function ReturnName() public view returns(string) {
  return created.receiveName();
 }

}
 contract foreignContract {
 string name;


 function changeName(string Name) public returns(bool) {
  name = Name;
  return true;
 }

 function receiveName() public view returns(string) {
  return name;
 }
}
```

Try out the following corrected code
It will compile and run without any Error.
No payable modifier is required for the code as you are not sending any ETH, the Only modification was using "new" keyword for creating contract instance.

Comment: CHANGE this created = foreignContract(msg.sender);
TO created = new foreignContract();
and it will work